# Where does 120 seconds timeout for FIN_WAIT_2 and CLOSE_WAIT come from?

Tags: c#, networking, timeout, tcpclient

I am testing my C# class that implements `TcpClient`. It works well, and also disconnecting works as expected: if the server closes the connection, the client goes into CLOSE_WAIT and the server goes into FIN_WAIT_2, until I call `Disconnect()` on the client. Everything as expected.

But during testing, I noticed some unexpected behaviour: If the time between the disconnect of server and client is longer than 120 seconds, the half-open connections are automatically closed by the operation system (Windows 10), as I can see in Sysinternals TcpView.

Who closes the connections? Windows? .NET? ... ?
Can I change this timeout? If yes, where?

The only related parameter I found is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/settings-that-can-be-modified-to-improve-network-performance

*Edits:*
I found more articles about half-closed connections. They state that timeouts for half-closed connections are common nowadays:
https://www.excentis.com/blog/tcp-half-close-cool-feature-now-broken
https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/pan-os/9-1/pan-os-admin/networking/session-settings-and-timeouts/tcp/tcp-half-closed-and-tcp-time-wait-timers
So it looks like this is also implemented in Windows 10 (and most likely in earlier versions of Windows as well).

Comment: TCP half closed is a bug in specification.  When TCP first tested by IEEE committee different software vendors implemented specification differently when both ends of connection are closed at same time.  TCP every action requires an ACK.  When both ends close at same time ACK does not get to one end of connection.  This race condition was never resolved by IEEE because it would of required some vendors to change their working code. So when both end of connection are from same vendor there is not an issue.  When both ends of connection is from different vendors you are left half open.

Comment: @jdweng This may be true (can you cite any source?), but it does not explain where the 120 seconds timeout comes from.

Comment: I took courses in college where the teacher explained the TCP ACK process.  I did some searching yesterday and did not find the windows service that actually closes the connection.

Comment: @jdweng I suppose the IEEE might look at TCP, but IEEE looks at physical network technologies (well, in this context at least) not protocols above Layer 2.  TCP is "covered" as it were by the IETF.

Comment: If both sides of a TCP connection attempt to close simultaneously, they will each be able to handle the FIN  of the other side, and the other side's ACK of that FIN.  And if one of the two ACKs is lost, that is not a problem in this case because FIN_WAIT_1 is an active retransmission state.  The side which did not receive the expected ACK will simply retransmit the FIN.

Comment: @RickJones : No!!!  Very rarely will two ends of a connection close at same and both ends send an ack.  When both ends close at approximately same time, one will not ACK.

Comment: @RickJones : IEE and IETF work hand-in-hand.  You can't separate hardware and software.  Over time a hardware implementation may be best, later in time software will be better, and then back to hardware.

Comment: When both ends close at the same time, both ends send FIN(ished) segments.   FIN segments are retransmitted until ACK(nowledged), or the maximum number of retransmissions is reached.